# Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following models and relationships:

[image: Picture of models]

A User has many Offers (where he/she is the seller), an Offer has many Purchases, a Purchase has many Accbooks

Models and associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers, foreign_key: :seller_id
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :buyer_id
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchases
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end

class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  has_one :seller, through: :offer
  has_many :accbooks,  class_name: 'Admin::Accbook', foreign_key: 'purchase_id' 
end

module Admin
  class Accbook < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :purchase
  end
end
```

I want to get all the Accbooks of any given user (as a seller). The equivalent SQL statement would look like this:

```
SELECT  "accbooks".* 
FROM "accbooks" 
INNER JOIN "purchases" ON "purchases"."id" = "accbooks"."purchase_id"
INNER JOIN "offers" ON "offers"."id" = "purchases"."offer_id"
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "offers"."seller_id"
WHERE "users"."id" = ?
```

So far I've tried this:

```
Admin::Accbook.joins( {purchase: :offer} )
```

Which gives me this SQL as a result:

```
SELECT  "accbooks".*
FROM "accbooks"
INNER JOIN "purchases" ON "purchases"."id" = "accbooks"."purchase_id"
INNER JOIN "offers" ON "offers"."id" = "purchases"."offer_id"
```

Now I don´t know how to add the join to the User model, and then how to add the Where condition.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You can do `Admin::Accbook.joins(purchase: { offer: :seller } ).where(users: { id: 123 })`

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Your answer works nicely with a slight variation in the Where, i.e.: Admin::Accbook.joins(purchase: { offer: :seller } ).where(offers: { seller_id: 123 }). If you post this as an answer I will mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `joins` the relations together and apply `where` clause on the joined relations:

```
Admin::Accbook
  .joins(purchase: :offer)
  .where(offers: { seller_id: 123 })
```

---

A thing to know, `where` uses the DB  table's name. `joins` (and `includes`, `eager_load`, etc) uses the relation name. This is why we have:

```
Admin::Accbook
  .joins(purchase: :offer)
  #                 ^^^^^ relation name
  .where(offers: { seller_id: 123 })
  #      ^^^^^^ table name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding following association in `users.rb`

`has_many :accbooks, through: :purchases`

Comment: Your answer is helpful, thanks a lot. However, it gives me all Accbooks where the user is the buyer (through purchases) and I am looking for Accbooks where she is the seller.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is user is acting as 2 roles for same accounts. You can try something like below stuff

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers, foreign_key: :seller_id
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :buyer_id
  has_many :offers_purchases,
           through: :offers,
           :class_name => 'Purchase',
           :foreign_key => 'offer_id',
           :source => :purchases
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not take into consideration the relationship with the Accbooks table. I need Accbooks that are children of a Purchase that is child of an Offer where a given user is the seller.